# Cassandra: read/s write/s

Tags: cassandra, throughput

I'm trying to figure out the throughput of my Cassandra cluster, and can't figure out how to use nodetool to accomplish that. Below is a sample output:

```
Starting NodeTool
Keyspace: realtimetrader
Read Count: 0
Read Latency: NaN ms.
Write Count: 402
Write Latency: 0.09648756218905473 ms.
Pending Flushes: 0
        Table: currencies
        SSTable count: 1
        Space used (live): 5254
        Space used (total): 5254
        Space used by snapshots (total): 0
        Off heap memory used (total): 40
        SSTable Compression Ratio: 0.0
        Number of keys (estimate): 14
        Memtable cell count: 1608
        Memtable data size: 567
        Memtable off heap memory used: 0
        Memtable switch count: 0
        Local read count: 0
        Local read latency: NaN ms
        Local write count: 402
        Local write latency: 0.106 ms
        Pending flushes: 0
        Bloom filter false positives: 0
        Bloom filter false ratio: 0,00000
        Bloom filter space used: 24
        Bloom filter off heap memory used: 16
        Index summary off heap memory used: 16
        Compression metadata off heap memory used: 8
        Compacted partition minimum bytes: 125
        Compacted partition maximum bytes: 149
        Compacted partition mean bytes: 149
        Average live cells per slice (last five minutes): 0.0
        Maximum live cells per slice (last five minutes): 0
        Average tombstones per slice (last five minutes): 0.0
        Maximum tombstones per slice (last five minutes): 0
```

I run the command:

```
nodetool cfstats
```

to get this, and then subtract the latter, "Local read count:" from the earlier one. 
But I'm not sure what the "Local" here means?
Does it mean its local to that node and in a ring of 5 nodes, I should multiple the value by 5? Or is it that the simple subtraction will give me the correct result?

Also, which JMX bean should I be looking at to get these #'s?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this [nodetool cfstats](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/tools/toolsCFstats.html).

I think what you are looking for is 'Read Latency' and 'Write Latency'.
These fields indicate how faster your read/writes are in your cluster.